# For Vim, is there a plugin that can help me manipulate strings like Rails Inflector?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I often need to change a string from one "format" to another, and find this tedious to do by hand.

Rails has a great [Inflector](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) api that allows one to manipulate strings like this, and this has been ported to other languages like Javascript [Inflect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inflect)

For example

```
MyClass -> my_class
MyClass -> my-class

My Title -> my-title
My Title -> my title
```

Etc.

Is there a Vim plugin that would let me do this while editing?

Comment: Vim is very customisable. Did you try to make a macro or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference I tried [Inflector.vim](https://github.com/farfanoide/inflector.vim) for a while but recently found [vim-caser](https://github.com/arthurxavierx/vim-caser) and prefer it as it's more full-featured.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Pope's [abolish.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) can do [text case coercion](https://vimtricks.com/p/vimtrick-text-case-coercion/). I'm not sure about your example with the space in it, that it might not do. But with the plugin installed, crs will change `MyClass` to `my_clas` and `cr-` will change it to `my-class`.